# Xamarin.Forms: How to get Tabbed Page throughout the app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to have `TabbedPage` throughout the app. In the first page Tab's are displaying fine. When I am starting second page From Tab1, It is hiding all tabs. How can I have Tab's all over the app.

[image: First page with tabs]
[image: Second page without tabs]

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedApp">
    <local:DairyTabs></local:DairyTabs>
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Tab 2"   
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
            Margin="5" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is the code from starting 2nd page

```
btnDemo.Clicked +=async delegate {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have TabbedPage throughout the app

You must add a `NavigationPage` as a child page in your TabbedPage in order to open pages inside the tab

So in your Xaml, you can have a `NavigationPage` inside TabbedPage

```
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedApp">
    <local:PageA/>
    <NavigationPage Title="Your Title">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MyPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Then you can add pages like this

```
public class MainPageCS : TabbedPage{
    public MainPageCS ()
    {
        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new MyPage ());

        navigationPage.Title = "Your title";

        Children.Add (new PageA ());
        Children.Add (navigationPage);
    }
}
```

So Navigation can be performed from this second page which is a instance of NavigationPage, like below

```
async void OnSomeButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2());
}
```

More info in this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page)

Comment: Here what is the difference between `PageA` and `MyPage`. `PageA` is outside of `NavigationPage`  and `MyPage` is inside.

Comment: Here `PageA` is your first tab which is a `ContentPage` and second tab is `MyPage` which is a `NavigationPage` which allows you to open another page inside this Tab

Comment: ok, when we go to 2nd tab(`MyPage`) It just start showing Navigationbar on top. Except that not changing anything.

Comment: oops, here `MyPage` must be a `ContentPage` as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

`Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());`

Instead of:

`Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());`